# Lightweight Threads in Operating Systems

Tags: multithreading, apache, node.js, twisted, evented-io

It is said that one of the main benefits of Node (and presumable twisted et al) over more conventional threaded servers, is the very high concurrency enabled by the event loop model. The biggest reason for this is that each thread has a high memory footprint and swapping contexts is comparatively expensive. When you have thousands of threads the server spends most of its time swapping from thread to thread.

My question is, why don't operating systems or the underlying hardware support much more lightweight threads? If they did, could you solve the 10k problem with plain threads? If they can't, why is that?

Comment: A thread is a sandbox, a sandbox is not cheap. Having an event loop avoids sandboxing.

Answer (score 3):

Modern operating systems can support the execution of a very large number of threads.

More generally, hardware keeps getting faster (and recently, it has been getting faster in a way that is much friendlier to multithreading and multiprocessing than to single-threaded event loops - ie, increased number of cores, rather than increased processing throughput capabilities in a single core).  If you can't afford the overhead of a thread today, you can probably afford it tomorrow.

What the cooperative multitasking systems of Twisted (and presumably Node.js et al) offers over pre-emptive multithreading (at least in the form of pthreads) is ease of programming.

Correctly using multithreading involves being much more careful than correctly using a single thread.  An event loop is just the means of getting multiple things done without going beyond your single thread.

Considering the proliferation of parallel hardware, it would be ideal for multithreading or multiprocessing to get easier to do (and easier to do *correctly*).  Actors, message passing, maybe even petri nets are some of the solutions people have attempted to solve this problem.  They are still very marginal compared to the mainstream multithreading approach (pthreads).  Another approach is SEDA, which uses multiple threads to run multiple event loops.  This also hasn't caught on.

So, the people using event loops have probably decided that programmer time is worth more than CPU time, and the people using pthreads have probably decided the opposite, and the people exploring actors and such would like to value both kinds of time more highly (clearly insane, which is probably why no one listens to them).

Comment: +1 for 'the people exploring actors and such would like to value both kinds of time more highly (clearly insane, which is probably why no one listens to them)'.  Yeah, and to make it more obvious, I'm a Stoke supporter!  (Martin James, 25 years of passing complex pooled classes to threads and thread pools).

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't really how heavyweight the threads are but the fact that to write correct multithreaded code you need locks on shared items and that prevents it from scaling with the number of threads because threads end up waiting for each other to gain locks and you rapidly reach the point where adding additional threads has no effect or even slows the system down as you get more lock contention.

In many cases you can avoid locking, but it's very difficult to get right, and sometimes you simply need a lock.

So if you are limited to a small number of threads, you might well find that removing the overhead of having to lock resources at all, or even think about it, makes a single threaded program faster than a multithreaded program no matter how many threads you add.

Basically locks can (depending on your program) be really expensive and can stop your program scaling beyond a few threads. And you almost always need to lock *something*.

It's not the overhead of a thread that's the problem, it's the synchronization between the threads. Even if you could switch between threads instantly, and had infinite memory none of that helps if each thread just ends up waiting in a queue for it's turn at some shared resource.